# Loop to queue a list n times in scheme

Tags: queue, scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a function that takes two parameters, a list and the number of times to loop, n. I've been trying to implement a let loop to call the helper function, save the result to a variable, then decrement n by 1 each loop and then stop when n reaches 0, but I'm not sure how exactly to do it..

Here's my code:

```
; helper function to queue it once
    (define (queue lst)
      (if (empty? lst)
          '()
      (append (cdr lst) (list (car lst)))))

;main function that calls helper function 
(define (queueLoop n lst)
 (if (empty? lst)
      '()
  (let loop ((res (queue lst))
             (lst (queue lst)))
    (cond
     [(> n 0)
      ((- n 1) (loop (queue res) (rest lst)))]
     (else
      (loop (queue res) (rest lst)))))))
```

Comment: Can you post an example of sample input with the expected output?

Comment: Sure. 

(check-expect (queueLoop 2 '(1 2 3 4)) '(3 4 1 2))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I would have done:

```
(define (rotate-left-inc lst n)
  (let-values ([(tail head) (split-at lst n)])
    (append head tail)))
```

As for a roll your own, using the fact that `cons` is O(1) and `append` is O(n) I'd do:

```
;; rotate once in O(n) time
(define (rotate-left-once lst)
  (append (cdr lst) (list (car lst))))

;; rotate n times in O(n) time
(define (rotate-left-on lst n)
  (let loop ([head lst] [rtail '()] [n n])
    (if (<= n 0)
        (append head (reverse rtail))
        (loop (cdr head) (cons (car head) rtail) (sub1 n)))))
```

While there is no way to repeat rotate-once and get a efficient procedure:

```
;; rotate n times in O(n^2) time
(define (rotate-left lst n)
  (let loop ([n n] [lst lst])
    (if (<= n 0)
        lst
        (loop (sub1 n) (rotate-left-once lst)))))
```

This get quite slow the longer the number you rotate when using the naive version, while the one using `append` once is much faster:

```
(define lst1 (make-list 200 198))
(define lst2 (make-list 20000 19998))
(define lst3 (make-list 2000000 1999998))
(for-each (lambda (lst)
            (display (car lst))
            (newline)
            (display "O(n) inc")
            (time (rotate-left-inc lst (car lst)))
            (display "O(n) roll")
            (time (rotate-left-on lst (car lst)))
            (display "O(n^2)")
            (time (rotate-left lst (car lst))))
          (list lst1 lst2 lst3))
```

Output on my computer clearly shows the exponential time takes a lot of time:

```
198
O(n) inccpu time: 1 real time: 0 gc time: 0
O(n) rollcpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
O(n^2)cpu time: 0 real time: 1 gc time: 0
19998
O(n) inccpu time: 1 real time: 0 gc time: 0
O(n) rollcpu time: 0 real time: 1 gc time: 0
O(n^2)cpu time: 4846 real time: 4884 gc time: 1295
1999998
O(n) inccpu time: 207 real time: 209 gc time: 160
O(n) rollcpu time: 279 real time: 282 gc time: 234
O(n^2) (didn't wait for it. Gave up after 5 minutes)
```

Comment: Ah I see. I was thinking of another solution where I would use <drop> and <take> as well. Using (append (drop lst n) (take lst n)) but it didn't seem to work if the n was greater than the length of the list.

Comment: @Electronic_Tear you're right. `n` needs to be less than the number of elements how I made it, but you could easily fix that with using  `(remainder n (length lst))` instead. Also with that a check for the empty list would also be nice since `(remainder 5 0)` will fail, but the result will be `()`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in Scheme most operations don't *mutate* variables, instead they return a new value with the modification. Take this, for instance:

```
(- n 1)
```

The above line is *not* modifying the value of `n`, it's returning a new value that is equal to `n` minus 1, and unless you store it somewhere or pass it as a parameter to a function call, the value will be lost (that's what's happening, in fact).

**UPDATE:** Now that you've posted a sample input/output, it's clear what you intended to do. Here's another simple way to write a solution using built-in procedures, which handles corner cases:

```
(define (queueLoop n lst)
  (let ((x (min n (length lst))))
    (append (drop lst x)
            (take lst x))))
```

For example:

```
(queueLoop 1 '())
=> '()
(queueLoop 0 '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(1 2 3 4)
(queueLoop 3 '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(4 1 2 3)
(queueLoop 5 '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: I see. That helps to see how you're doing the decrement loop. It's close, but I should've been more descriptive. My goal is to take pop the first element off and move it to the end of the list, and repeat that procedure n times.

Comment: @Electronic_Tear But that is not very effiecent. The best would be to build a list as you iterate how many you would like to have in the in the end and then do a `(append rest built-list)` once. Doing rotate n times makes the procedure O(n^2) instead of O(n), that is it increases exponentially with the number of elements you want to move. `(queueLoop 1337 (make-list 2000 1))` might take longer than expected.

Comment: @Electronic_Tear alright! now it's clear, I've updated my answer with a simple solution.